# image draw on canvas looks distorted

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, canvas

I am using cordova to get image either from camera or gallery. The way I am putting it on canvas is as follows:

```
function getImageFromCamera(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccessCamera, onFailureCamera, {
       quality: 25,
       destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
       correctOrientation: true,
       allowEdit:false
    });

 function onSuccessCamera(imageURI) {
    var c=document.getElementById("picture");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var showImg = new Image;
    showImg.onload = function(){
           c.width = this.width;
           c.height = this.height;
                                                      ctx.drawImage(this,0,0);
                                            };

    showImg.src = url;
  }
}
```

html:

```
<canvas id="picture"></canvas>
```

This works fine but some images looks very horrible or cut down due to the fix 300, 400 size. I am wondering how do i get it fix so that image is as i see in the gallery?

Comment: `img.onload = function(){ c.width = this.width; c.height = this.height; ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);`

Comment: this keeps my code still working but i dont see any difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phonegap camera draw on canvas distorted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29151943/phonegap-camera-draw-on-canvas-distorted)

Comment: And you are not setting the canvas width and height to fixed values through CSS ?

Comment: I had it earlier in the above canvas itself but removed based. On first comment